# Converting rxjs retryWhen to retry

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following snippet which relies on the retryWhen,how do I convert to the retry as retryWhen is deprectaed.

```
return src.pipe(
            retryWhen((errors: Observable<any>) => errors.pipe(
                mergeMap(error => {
                        if (retries-- > 0) {
                            const backoffTime = delayMs + (maxRetry + retries) + backoffMs;
                            return of(error).pipe(delay(backoffTime));
                        }
                        console.error(`retryWithBackoff exceeded url: ${url} max: ${maxRetry} ${error} ${errors} ${error.status} ${error.statusText} ${error.url}`);
                        return of(`network error ${error.statusText} ${url} ${maxRetry}`);
                    }
                )
            ))
        );
```

Comment: As mentioned in the [docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retryWhen): Instead of `retryWhen(() => notify$)`, use: `retry({ delay: () => notify$ })`.

Answer (score 0):

ended up doing:

```
import {Observable, of, retry, timer} from "rxjs";
import {StoreSelectorsService} from "../../app/services";
import {actionNetworkRequest} from "../../app/store/actions/user.actions";
import {ToastrService} from "ngx-toastr";
import {catchError, map} from "rxjs/operators";

const CONFIG = {count: 3, delay: 200, url: ''};

export function backoffRetry<T>({count, delay, url} = CONFIG) {
    return (obs$: Observable<T>) => obs$.pipe(
        retry({
            count, delay: (error, retryIndex) => {
                const d = Math.pow(2, retryIndex - 1) * delay;
                console.log(`count ${retryIndex} of ${count}  delay ${delay} for ${url}`);
                if (retryIndex === count) {
                    console.error(`retryWithBackoff exceeded url: ${url} max: ${retryIndex}`);
                    return of(`network error ${url} ${count} ${error} ${error.message} ${error.statusText} ${error.url}`);
                }
                return timer(d);
            }
        })
    );
}

export function retryWithBackoff<U>(url: string, storeSelectorService: StoreSelectorsService, toastr: ToastrService, delayMs: number = 2000, maxRetry: number = 6): any {
    return <T>(src: Observable<T>): Observable<any> => {
        const retries = maxRetry;
        if (storeSelectorService) {
            storeSelectorService.dispatch(actionNetworkRequest({url}));
        }
        return src.pipe(
            backoffRetry({count: retries, delay: delayMs, url}),
            catchError((v) => {
                alert('error maxed');
                return v;
            })
        );
        
    };
}
```